# PHP can't upload videos from iphone to server

Tags: php

I am having an issue.

Someone wrote this **upload code** for my client, and now I am trying to fix it, but i am lost.

I can upload videos from mobile and desktop, but if its `*.mov` format it will not work.

And here is the [link](http://ideone.com/3Z1sSd) with the php and the [website](http://eyecandybox.tv/index.php).

If you may please take a look and guide me i would really appreciate it.

```
    if ($upd) {
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if ($imageFileType != "mp4" && $imageFileType != "avi" && $imageFileType != "mov" && $imageFileType != "3gp" && $imageFileType != "mpeg") { ?>
        <div class="errorFormat"><p>File Format Not Suppoted</p></div>
    <?php } else {
```

Comment: In side the `if` statement, `var_dump($imageFileType);` to confirm that the type is what you think it is.

Comment: @PatrickQ  its not working .I think the issue is with the code that transform video into an image ,but i still dont understand why i cant upload iphone formats.

Comment: Not working _how_? What are you expecting to happen? What actually _is_ happening? Are you getting errors? If so, what? Have you checked your error logs? Also, most of us are not going to follow links to view your code or anything else. Whatever is important to the question should be included directly in _the question itself_.

Comment: @PatrickQ on desktop it only echo's the error "fille not supported " , no errors in the log .And on mobile it redirects me  on the same page with white background where it echo's your images was not a gif .jpg ... etc .